# Reporting services with custom assembly returning a Dataset

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

I need to generate a rather complex report. The output is a simple tabular result, but that table is built from different pieces of data from several physical tables.

Currently I'm using a stored procedure that returns the desired result, but using T-SQL is becoming very difficult to maintain.

I would like to replace the SP by some C# code. My questions are:

- can the report (RDL) use the returned Dataset from the custom assembly and bind it to a Tablix?
- if so, how can I determine the connection string at runtime, in order to pass that information to the custom assembly?

Comment: How is writing the query in C# going to simplify things? You still need to write T-SQL (inline) to send to the DB, unless you use Linq.

Comment: Randy: this is not 1 query, but dozens, mixed with complex logic; some of that complexity would be better addressed with C# rather than T-SQL.